# Visual studio 2012 ultimate (URL error with images)

Tags: nsurlerrordomain

I am using Visual Studio 2012 ultimate.

I have 19 images that i want to display within an app i'm creating. Six of these images have the same package name, URL and file type (.png) as the rest,and they're not having any issues at all. 
The other 13 however, all have warnings attached when i run the debug tool.

This is the warning below:

DOM7009: unable to decode image at URL:  'ms-appx://e013fe8c-2730-4937-b5ca-e49b7c83e78e/images/coin_1.png'.

If anyone has any knowledge in regards to solving this, that would be awesome.

note: When i run the debug program cross boxes appear where the images should be shown.

note: I am using Visual Studio on Windows 10.